# Why does this circuit flash the two LEDs even without a 555 timer?

Tags: basic

Can you please help understanding how this circuit is flashing the two LEDs? I know about transistors, capacitors, and resistors functionality, but can't get how this works without a 555 timer.

[image]

Comment: asks google about: astable multivibrator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Astable multivibrator using transistor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/361298/astable-multivibrator-using-transistor)

Comment: Did you read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivibrator#Astable_multivibrator)?

Comment: Pretty much every circuit I've ever designed works well without having a 555 timer fitted. Yours is no exception.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The capacitors will alternate between being charged and discharged, thereby turning on and off the transistors making the LEDs blink alternately. This is a passive circuit, no need for a NE555.

More information on:
https://www.build-electronic-circuits.com/astable-multivibrator/

It is called an astable multivibrator circuit.

Comment: It isn't a passive circuit.  Transistors are usually counted as active devices.  The circuit is built of discrete components (no IC,) but it is not passive.

Answer (score 1):

The 555 timer is an integrated circuit intended to make it easier to build oscillators and timed pulses.

Your circuit is an [astable multivibrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivibrator) made with discrete transistors.

The [555](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC) is an integrated circuit containing a bucket of transistors in a very small volume:

[image]

<sub>Image from the linked Wikipedia article.</sub>

The 555 makes it possible to do things that a simple oscillator can't, but it is still built of transistors (and other components.)

ICs aren't magic boxes with [little demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_demon) inside kicking electrons around.

They are complex electronic circuits with a known and defined structure and function.  Some of them could be duplicated with individual parts - you can buy discrete 555 kits with standard components that you can assemble into a functional (though large) 555.  Others are so complex (microprocessors, for example) that the equivalent circuit made of standard components would be too large to be practical (or even work.)